# Developing a Qt app for Android from the command line

Tags: android, macos, qt

I would like to compile and deploy on an Android device a simple helloworld program written using Qt **purely** using vi/emacs and the OS X command line, without using QtCreator or Android Studio.

[This](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Android) page describes how to fill in values for `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`, etc, before compiling Qt5. I have in the past used QtCreator to compile for Android without having to compile Qt itself, and I'm now wondering whether it's possible to use a command-line toolchain to do the same.

The steps I've taken so far are:

1. Installed the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools).
2. Installed the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).
3. Installed Qt5 by `sudo port install qt5-mac`.

After this last step, I duly see `/opt/local/share/qt5/mkspecs/android-g++`, which suggests that the first step ought to be `qmake -spec android-g++`.

Have you successfully compiled on OS X and deployed to Android a Qt project from the command line without having to compile Qt itself?

**Update**

Running `sudo port install qt5-mac` on OS X appears not to install Qt-for-android. Download instead [qt-opensource-mac-x64-1.6.0-8-online.dmg](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/). Mount/run. Click until `Select Components`. Make sure `Android armv7` is selected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need:
- Java JDK
- Apache ANT
- Android SDK
- Android NDK
- Qt for Android

Set the environment variables (change accordingly):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Path/To/AndroidSDK  
export ANDROID_NDK_HOST=linux-x86  
export ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM=android-12  
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/Path/To/AndroidNDK  
export ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=arm-linux-androideabi  
export ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8  
export ANDROID_NDK_TOOLS_PREFIX=arm-linux-androideabi  
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Path/To/AndroidSDK  
export ANDROID_API_VERSION=android-12  

export JAVA_HOME=/Path/To/JavaJDK  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/Path/To/ApacheANT/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

If you're on OS X, use the following line instead:

```
export ANDROID_NDK_HOST=darwin-x86_64
```

Build for Android:

```
mkdir build_myproj_android  
cd build_myproj_android  
/Path/To/QtForAndroid/bin/qmake -r -spec android-g++ /Path/To/MyProject/MyProject.pro  
make  
make install INSTALL_ROOT=android  
/Path/To/QtForAndroid/bin/androiddeployqt --output android --verbose --input android-libMyProject.so-deployment-settings.json
```

And finally, deploy using:

```
/Path/to/AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb install /Path/to/build_myproj_android/android/bin/QtApp-debug.apk
```

Comment: This recipe no longer works on El Capitan  (10.11.5) with either Qt 5.6.0 or 5.7.0. With just a `QPushButton button("Hello"); button.show();` everything in the chain described in the answer works fine, but when launched on a (vanilla Nexus) device it bombs with "Unfortunately, .. has stopped". Hints welcome.

Comment: From 5.6 you can download only AMRv7 version of prebuild Qt. Make sure that your device can run ARM7 binaries. (You can also test with 5.5 AMRv5 version)

Comment: The device's instruction set does handle ARMv7. It bombs with 5.5.1 as well as with 5.7.0.

Comment: One tiny note here: `export ANDROID_NDK_HOST=linux-x86_64`

Comment: One more tiny note: for android arm64_v8a, `ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=aarch64-linux-android` and `export ANDROID_NDK_TOOLS_PREFIX=aarch64-linux-android`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Marian that has wrote a complete response. just if you are going to sign your package too, say it to androiddeployqt by:

```
/Path/To/QtForAndroid/bin/androiddeployqt --output android --verbose --input android-libMyProject.so-deployment-settings.json --sign <url/to/keystore> <alias> --storepass <password>
```

Comment: Thanks for the important addition. If you've done a round-trip, please look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/38575925/704972